# IntelliJ Unable to find the path specified to a file in a Junit Test

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have a test in IntelliJ (`package: com.company.project.testClasses`, path: `src/test/java/tests/TestClass.java`) that uses a file in a resources folder(`package: testData.testDataFile.templatevalues`, path: `src/test/resources/testData/DataFile.file`). In IntelliJ before today, this test would run successfully.

However, whenever I run the test within IntelliJ, I receive the following error:
`java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified`.

The exception is being thrown in the File.java class (from java.io, jdk1.8.0_101) during the `f.getPath()`

```
 if (!fs.createFileExclusively(f.getPath()))
        throw new IOException("Unable to create temporary file");

    return f;
}
```

I am able to run the test successfully on its own through command line as well as through eclipse.

The only thing I have noticed in IntelliJ that is different over the last year is that it has started to to notify me when I run the tests that: `Command line is too long. In order to reduce its length classpath file can be used. Would you like to enable classpath file mode for all run configurations of your project` and I must enable that within IntelliJ to begin running the test.

I have checked to make sure I have the most up-to-date version of IntelliJ (As of writing this post it is 2017.2.4) as well as restarting IntelliJ and my PC.

Is there any known solution to allow IntelliJ to recognize the file so I do not need to leave the IDE to run these tests?

Comment: How do you define `f`?

Comment: As @CrazyCoder said, please show the line where you create f. We need to see the path you are giving it. We also need to know your directory structure. FYI resources are packages, not just directories. If you put the resources in the same package as the relevant class it'll be easier to locate. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html "A common convention for the name of a resource used by a class is to use the fully qualified name of the package of the class, but convert all periods (.) to slashes (/), and add a resource name of the form name.extension."

Comment: f is defined in the File.java class which is in the java.io package. I am calling it through various API's until it gets to the File.java class in which IntelliJ claims it cannot find the path

Comment: Link to File.java class within java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: It seems to be linked to the command line issue in IntelliJ. It seems like classpath file mode is not able to find the path I am giving for the files.

Comment: Does your IntelliJ project have multiple modules? You may have to specify the module name as part of the path, or set the project context to the specific module you're testing.

Comment: No it doesn't have multiple modules. And I want to stress that this runs through the command line with a gradle command as well as through eclipse. So I would rather not change my file path to something else just to get it to work with IDEA, I would rather have the fix be within IntelliJ